# Cortana channel registration failed

Tags: azure-bot-service

I'm having the following error shown when i try to enable Cortana bot channel service: 'Sorry, Something went wrong'

Not sure what's the cause of this problem.

Worth mentioning that i'm trying this via organisational tenant, which means i'm invited on organisation to publish the app with Application Admin role. My account time is Business one (not personal account).
**strong text**
I have contacted account owner to try this same Cortana Channel registration, but this option isn't visible on their account (no Cortana channel available).[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/third-party-deprecation) documentation,

1. **Consumer-facing Cortana services have been deprecated by the Cortana team.**
   The bot or bot service will not be impacted by this change and will continue to be available, except for the Cortana channel changes that are outlined below.
2. If you are an existing developer with a Cortana skill deployed to “self,” “test,” or “world,” the Cortana channel configuration page will remain available for a 30-day period, beginning August 6, 2020. During this period, if you submit your skill for certification and it passes the guidelines, it will be made available.
3. On September 7, 2020, **Cortana will be removed from the Channels page as an available channel for third-party developers**.
4. On September 7, 2020, **all Cortana third-party consumer skills built with the Cortana skills kit will be retired**.

Comment: Can you please accept the answer so that it helps others as well with a similar query? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

As Ranusharao mentioned above, Cortana skills kit has been retired. For now, **Cortana skills kit** for Enterprise will continue to be available for TAP customers to build skills for their organization.

For information is please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/enterprise/overview